# angular routing parameter not accessible

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

**EDIT:** (solution)

The root-cause of my problem was, that there had been additional routes added programmatically within the app.component. I found this by disabling all routes in the app-routing.module and still being mysteriously able to navigate to the route in question. After removing the programmatically added routes everything was working as expected. Thanks for the help everyone! :-)

**ORIGINAL** (question):

I am using the following code within my component to subscribe to parameters of the route:

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((values) => {
  console.log('these are my parameters: ', values);
});
```

Everything works fine, I get the parameters of the route without any problems.

This is the working configuration of the route:

```
{
  path: 'details/:itemId',
  component: ItemDetailsComponent,
},
```

**Now to the problem:**
When I try to simplify my route (since I do not need any other routes) the following problem arises: After making the following simple change to the route-configuration, I cannot access the route-parameters anymore (they are empty).

This is the defective configuration of the route:

```
{
  path: ':itemId',
  component: ItemDetailsComponent,
},
```

Does anybody know, why I cannot access the single route-parameter anymore after I shortend the route?

Comment: have you try `/:itemId`?

Comment: Does that mean that you want associate ItemDetailsComponent with the route url of your app ?

Comment: @Mehdi yes, exactly

Comment: @Abhishek I tried that, but angular complains about routes not beginning with a slash

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're still trying to navigate to `details/:itemId` when you should have done it for just `:itemId`. Make sure you're navigating to the proper path.

After you've done the change, `/details` would work and would be considered as `itemId`. But `/details/1` or any such path would result in an error.

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gafgso?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: your stackblitz works! But it does not work within my applocation... I put in the route by hand

Comment: @TobiasGassmann, what route did you put? Please tell me the exact path that you're trying to navigate your user to.

Comment: www.example.com/123

Comment: and I cannot get my hands on the "123"

Comment: and the correct component is instatiated, I checked that with console.logs. Simply the route-param is missing

Comment: Can you please fork my StackBlitz link and make changes as per your scenario so that you can replicate this issue?

Comment: I will try that, but as it seems in stackblitz everything works fine...

Answer (score 1):

It does work fine. See the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nqzpum

Comment: Create a stackblitz please

Comment: It seems I cannot reproduce my local problem in a stackblitz.. in stackblitz it works fine.. I will keep trying

Comment: If the route configuration is inside some module other than the AppModule, then you may need to subscribe to the parent's params using `this.activatedRoute.parent.params.subscribe`

Answer (score 1):

in this case you don't really need to specify the variable in your router.module which should look like this :

```
{
  path: '',
  component: ItemDetailsComponent,
},
```

Then if you need to open a item in particular then use the

```
this.router.navigate(["", {itemId: 123}]);
```

provided that router is injected as **Router** where is call is made.

Then you need to inject in your ItemDetailsComponent **activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute**

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
  (params) => {
    //ItemId will be available here when url changes
    console.log(params.itemId);
  }
);
```